# Google maps API - removing drop down box showing results

Tags: google-maps

I have the following script to add markers to a map:-

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDHIP7rWh6XQFCO_dPIVnW3TXMZ4fiRtSY" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var infoWindow;
    var locationSelect;

    function load() {
        map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( "map" ), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng( 54, -2 ),
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: 'terrain',
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            }
        } );
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        locationSelect = document.getElementById( "locationSelect" );
        locationSelect.onchange = function () {
            var markerNum = locationSelect.options[ locationSelect.selectedIndex ].value;
            if ( markerNum != "none" ) {
                google.maps.event.trigger( markers[ markerNum ], 'click' );
            }
        };
    }

    function searchLocations() {
        var address = document.getElementById( "addressInput" ).value;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( {
            address: address, 'componentRestrictions':{'country':'GB'}
        }, function ( results, status ) {
            if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                searchLocationsNear( results[ 0 ].geometry.location );
            } else {
                alert( address + ' not found' );
            }
        } );
    }

    function clearLocations() {
        infoWindow.close();
        for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
            markers[ i ].setMap( null );
        }
        markers.length = 0;

        locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
        var option = document.createElement( "option" );
        option.value = "none";
        option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
        locationSelect.appendChild( option );
    }

    function searchLocationsNear( center ) {
        clearLocations();

        var radius = document.getElementById( 'radiusSelect' ).value;
        var searchUrl = '/maps/genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
        downloadUrl( searchUrl, function ( data ) {
            var xml = parseXml( data );
            var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName( "marker" );
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for ( var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++ ) {
                var name = markerNodes[ i ].getAttribute( "name" );
                var address = markerNodes[ i ].getAttribute( "address" );
                var distance = parseFloat( markerNodes[ i ].getAttribute( "distance" ) );
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat( markerNodes[ i ].getAttribute( "lat" ) ),
                    parseFloat( markerNodes[ i ].getAttribute( "lng" ) ) );

                createOption( name, distance, i );
                createMarker( latlng, name, address );
                bounds.extend( latlng );
            }
            map.fitBounds( bounds );
            locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
            locationSelect.onchange = function () {
                var markerNum = locationSelect.options[ locationSelect.selectedIndex ].value;
                google.maps.event.trigger( markers[ markerNum ], 'click' );
            };
        } );
    }

    function createMarker( latlng, name, address ) {
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b>";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
            map: map,
            position: latlng
        } );
        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.setContent( html );
            infoWindow.open( map, marker );
        } );
        markers.push( marker );
    }

    function createOption( name, distance, num ) {
        var option = document.createElement( "option" );
        option.value = num;
        option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed( 1 ) + ")";
        locationSelect.appendChild( option );
    }

    function downloadUrl( url, callback ) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' ) :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if ( request.readyState == 4 ) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback( request.responseText, request.status );
            }
        };

        request.open( 'GET', url, true );
        request.send( null );
    }

    function parseXml( str ) {
        if ( window.ActiveXObject ) {
            var doc = new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLDOM' );
            doc.loadXML( str );
            return doc;
        } else if ( window.DOMParser ) {
            return ( new DOMParser ).parseFromString( str, 'text/xml' );
        }
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
</script>
```

This code produces the map as required and adds the markers in the correct places. However at the top of the map there is a dropdown box titled "see all results" which I want remove. The web page in question is [Find a Walk](https://www.walkingbritain.co.uk/find-walks-by-me.php)

Can anyone suggest how this can be done? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the HTML element with id "locationSelect" (HTML not provided in question), remove the code that is populating it.

Comment: By removing the element with id "locationSelect" the markers disppear.

Comment: Any Javascript errors?  Did you remove the code that is populating it?

Comment: I dont think there are any javascript errors as the page has been working fine. I did try removing the section of JS that populates the element as well as the element but again the resuult is the markers fail to appear.

Comment: Usually when the markers "fail to appear" there is a javascript error in the console that explains why.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the element with id `locationSelect`, your JavaScript code will crash as there are parts in the code that reference this element.

So in addition to deleting `<select id="locationSelect">` from your HTML, you also need to remove the variable `locationSelect` and all references to it from your JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll give it a go tomorrow as I have spent the day working through the code and have just about had enough!

Comment: Got it; yeah, it can get tiring. Hopefully you manage to resolve the issue soon.

Comment: I spent a few hours trying to do this but my Javascript knowledge is not the best in the world! Thanks for all the input nevertheless.